# How compare two times in Carbon?

Tags: php, laravel

Here are two times in db in time format: "10:00:00" and "11:00:00".

I have tried to compare them:

```
 $starttime = Carbon::parse($icomingdate['"starttime']);
 $endtime = Carbon::parser($icomingdate["endtime"]);

if($starttime + 30 > $endtime && $endtime <= '23:59:00') {
   echo "Greated then start time + 30 minutes";
}
```

How to do that properly in Carbon?

My full code is:

```
 $date1 = ["date" => "2022-10-23", "starttime" => "10:00:00", "endtime" => "11:00:00"];
        $date2 = ["date" => "2022-10-23", "starttime" => "11:00:00", "endtime" => "12:00:00"];
        $icomedate = ["date" => "2022-10-23", "starttime" => "10:00:00", "endtime" => "10:30:00"];
        $dates = [$date1, $date2];

        try {

            $starttime = Carbon::parse($icomedate["starttime"]);
            $endtime = Carbon::parse($icomedate["endtime"]);
            $date = Carbon::parse($icomedate["date"]);
            $interval = 30;

            if ($endtime < $starttime) {
                throw new Error("End time should be greate start time");
            }

            if($endtime < $starttime->addMinutes($interval)) {
                throw new \Exception("Interval");
            }

            if($endtime > $date->endOfDay()) {
                throw new \Exception("End time can not be more then end of day");
            }

            if($starttime < $date->startOfDay()) {
                throw new \Exception("End time can not be less then start of day");
            }

            foreach ($dates as $date) {
                $stime = Carbon::parse($date["starttime"]);
                $etime = Carbon::parse($date["endtime"]);

                if ($starttime >= $stime && $starttime <= $etime) {
                    throw new \Exception("Start\Endtime time crossed");
                }
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            dd($e->getMessage());
        }
```

So I try to check times for selected date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your model cast your columns to dates, with the date format on the cast property.

```
class YourModel {
    protected $casts= [
        'starttime' => 'datetime:H:m:s',
        'endtime' => 'datetime:H:m:s',
    ];
}
```

Now your model will return dates, Carbon has a lot of [comparison](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-comparison) functions and you can use. Your endtime comparison does not make sense, as if you do not have the date as your format states, it can not be more than 23:59.

```
$yourModel = YourModel::find(42);


if($yourModel->starttime->addMinutes(30)->gt($yourModel->endtime)) {

}
```

Comment: As a note, since i posted this you changed your question significant, right now i'm not gonna change my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`Carbon` has comparison methods to make this possible easily. Such as :

- `eq()` or `equalTo()` – Dates are equal
- `ne()` or `notEqualTo()` – Date are not equal
- `gt()` or `greaterThan()` or `isAfter()` – Date greater than another date
- `gte()` or `greaterThanOrEqualTo()` – Date greater than or equal to another date
- `lt()` or `lessThan()` or `isBefore()` – Date less than another date
- `lte()` or `lessThanOrEqualTo()` – Date less than or equal to another date
- `between()` or `isBetween()` / `betweenIncluded()` /
- `betweenExcluded()` – Date is between two other dates

So for your comparison above, you can do it this way:

```
$starttime = Carbon::parse($icomingdate['"starttime']);
 $endtime = Carbon::parser($icomingdate["endtime"]);

if(($starttime->addMinutes(30)->gt($endtime) && $endtime->lte('23:59:00')) {
   echo "Greated than start time + 30 minutes";
}
```